# Is dying while asleep considered bad as per any scripture?

Tags: belief, death, rebirth

If someone dies in their sleep, generally people say - *"what a peaceful (and painless) way to pass away"*.

However, recently I heard a priest say that as per Hinduism this kind of death is considered bad or unfortunate for the departed jīvātmā. According to him, it's important that one is conscious while the *prāṇa* leaves the body.

Citing something very similar to [BG 8.6](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=8&field_nsutra_value=6&etsiva=1&etgb=1&choose=1) he opined that dying while asleep, leads to tāmsika-yonī, since the jīvātmā at sleep is predominantly surrounded by tamas.

In any case, does any scriptures deliberate and discuss on this issue?

##### Is it an unfortunate death as per scriptures, if a person dies while they're asleep?

Also, does any scripture say it's better to be completely conscious while dying?

If not any text, does any authoritative preceptor discuss this?

---

Related, but not duplicate questions -

- [Remain conscious while dying?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34223/remain-conscious-while-dying)
- [What can one do to enjoy death or the dying process?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28106/what-can-one-do-to-enjoy-death-or-the-dying-process)
- [Is it true that the next life depends on our thoughts while dying?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27746/is-it-true-that-the-next-life-depends-on-our-thoughts-while-dying)

Comment: I like this question and would love to read the answers. Speaking of the other way i.e dying conscious, there are examples like suicide and suicide by Adolf Hitler which won't fit into fortune death. Just my opinion.

Comment: Well, good-point @SeverusSnape , however, by 'conscious-death' we would generally imply natural death. Suicide is already condemned and a sure-shot way to attain preta-hood in the scriptures.