# According to Dvaita philosophy , is Parmatma involved in Karma?

Tags: karma, atma, dvaita

Parmatma is not just a witness.[In my previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/according-to-dvaita-philosophy-why-is-paramatma-worshiped) it became apparent that the Parmatma had certain responsibilities to fulfill. Parmatma is bestower of blessings and punishment. If a person does a good job then he or she is blessed and if he does a bad job then he is punished by Parmatma.

My question are :

If Parmatma has responsibilities to fulfill then isn't he doing Karma and therefore liable to suffer the consequences of Karma?

(For example Bhagwan Vishnu had given Narada monkey face( this was Vishu's Karma) and Narada cursed Lord Vishnu that he will be seperated from his beloved ones(this was the consequence of Vishnu's Karma).)

Answer (score 2):

```
 ... Parmatma had certain responsibilities to fulfill.
```

**NO**.
How did you get that impression from the previous Qn? I don't see anywhere such thing explained in that post.

**Paramatma has no responsibility to fulfil**.
Not only Paramatma (supreme self), but in fact, no being has any responsibility to fulfil. It's just a perception due to illusion. Refer:
[How to know What is the purpose of my life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20242/1049)

```
good job is blessed and ... bad job punished by Parmatma.
```

**NO**.
Neither good nor bad Karma-s, reach till the supreme self.

> BG 5.15 - **The Omnipresent neither accepts anybody's sin nor even good deeds**. Knowledge remains covered by ignorance. Thus the creatures become deluded.

```
isn't he doing Karma and therefore liable to suffer the consequences of Karma?
```

**NO**.
Though the supreme Brahman does Karma-s, they don't bind him. Because Brahman acts upon it being disinterested & detached. One gets consequence of something, when one is interested.

> BG 9.9 - O Arjuna, those **actions (Karma-s) don't bind Me, as "I" am indifferent (disinterested) & detached** to those actions

```
According to Dvaita philosophy , is Parmatma involved in Karma?
```

**Yes**.
Let's assume Krishna as the earthly form of the supreme self.
He declared during Gita that:

> BG 3.22 - **In all the three worlds, O Partha, there is no responsibility for Me to fulfil**; Nothing remains un-achieved or to be achieved. **Still I continue in Karma**.

Comment: Not bad answer, actually it's good one, but I have one objection and suggestion, I think you should delete *Not only Paramatma (supreme self), but in fact, no being has any responsibility to fulfil. It's just a perception due to illusion.* because that is not what Dvaita teach. The question was about Dvaita perspective on those matters.

Comment: "How did you get that impression from the previous Qn?" The discussion was in comments with brahma jhana.. I thought it would be better to ask it as a question. You said- "Neither good nor bad Karma-s, reach till the supreme self." If this is true then what is the point of doing good karma ? Paramtma is the Lord of all sacrifices. Suppose I do sacrifices for him, will it not reach to the Lord Krishna ?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa, the reason for keeping *"no being has any responsibility"* -- is that, if Gita is *advaita-dvaita-vishishtadvaita-..* or not -- is debated. According to people's own lenses they see it. IMO, *dvaita* or *advaita* are states. A person **cannot believe dvaita/advaita**, but would attain those state. Hence, I avoid treating it as a philosophy as such. For this post, I have been loyal to title Qn only w.r.t Dvaita. Other parts are just normal perspective. However, feel free to edit the way you feel right, with keeping the meaning intact. Thx. :-)

Comment: @DheerajVerma, *"If this is true then what is the point of doing good karma ?"* -- You got it right. Actually there is no point. If people want to get good fruits, then they do good Karma and for bad fruits they do bad Karma. In any case, they don't go beyond the Prakruti made up of 3 modes. -- *"I do sacrifices for him, will it not reach to the Lord Krishna"* -- in a way everything ultimately reaches to supreme, it's just if it's done with good/bad/mix intention, the intermediate deity situated in Prakruti will reply to it. If "no intention" then it will reach the supreme (e.g. Krishna).

Comment: iammilind, I'll not edit your post to change your thoughts therein. If you agree with my suggestion you can change it yourself. I just gave a suggestion. "*no being has any responsibility to fulfil*" and "*It's just a perception due to illusion*" are not consistent with the teaching of Dvaita.