# If Parmatma is within me then can I pray to myself?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma

It is said that Parmatma is within me. And it is also said that prayer to any demigod or ghosts or spirits indirectly goes to Parmatma only.

So my question is : Can I pray to myself and receive the blessings of Parmatma ?

Comment: If you feel you can answer your prayers (i.e. bless yourself), then sure. If not, better to go to a temple.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. I want to pray to the Parmatma within me. That paramatma will give the blessing. When a person prays to a ghost or ghoul the prayer ultimately goes to the Paramatma. Similarly when I pray to myself the prayer goes to the Supreme Lord.

Comment: Are these ur genuine questions or are u asking just for the sake of asking? BTW there's indeed something called Atma Puja. Puja of the Shiva-Self within us which is done before the Deity worship.

Comment: Of course these are genuine questions. If you notice most of my questions are around atma and parmatma. That is what I am interested in knowing about. If Atma puja is allowed then please post that as an answer. I plan to pray to myself if that is true.

Comment: "I want to pray to the Parmatma within me. That paramatma will give the blessing." - this requires practice of yoga.

Comment: The Paramatma within you is what remains after you subtract out your body-mind complex. If you are capable of worshipping 'yourself' then you have attained Samadhi and directly experienced 'yourself'. This is the ultimate goal of Advaita sadhana.

Comment: Great!! The answer appears to be yes according to Advaita sidhanta but what about the answer from the point of view of Dvaita sidhanta? (Why not somebody put it all as an answer? It will be of great help to everybody.Thanks.)

Comment: In many other religions, people pray with their head held high, pointing towards sky but in Hinduism, we generally do pray with our head held low pointing to ourselves.

Comment: @Santanu I am unable to understand how your comment is relevant to the question.

Comment: My comment signifies that actually we pray to ourselves.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, ... But ask to your(??)self who is praying? Parmatma or your psycho-physical existence? If psycho-physical existence wants to pray then to whom it wants to pray? And how would you know to whom you are praying? Other than Paramatma- you have mind as well? How will you ensure to pray to Paramatma only, not to the mind since you don't have any clue how Parmatma existing in you? Where you will find him/her(?) in the body to pray??????????  So, being a psycho - physical existence you can't pray to the Parmatma residing in you. This is the reason of existence of dualistic & semi-dualistic hindu philosophies.

But...Yes, there is a way to pray yourself but the way is such the sentence `there is a way to pray yourself` too become a paradox. Because then you don't pray you just exist. You do so by become pure existence alone. You will then have to shift your ontology to Parabhairava state. Then the **I** is Shiva & the subjective feeling of the **existence of I** is Shakti. Then the prayer, the one who is praying, & the one whom you pray all become one. Lord Krishna said this Brahman Yajna. Brahma yajna is what you are looking for. But it is difficult to practice. In any case, this is the how you can pray to yourself - called Brahman Yajna. This is very deep & one of the most esoteric verse of Bhagvad Geeta, I would end up with verse only without commentary.

> For those who are completely absorbed in God-consciousness, the oblation is Brahman, the ladle with which it is offered is Brahman, the act of offering is Brahman, and the sacrificial fire is also Brahman. Such persons, who view everything as God, easily attain him. BG-4.24

we say this in this way.

> Whatever I take is offered to Lord Śiva. Whatever I have to offer is for Lord Śiva. Whatever I offer is itself Lord Śiva. I have to offer Lord Śiva in Lord Śiva.

---

Btw, you were not the first to ask this question. same question was asked long before, although in different ways.

> The goddess said "Great lord, if such is the nature of the
>   Supreme Sakti, then in the admittedly established rules of
>   spiritual life, **who would be invoked in recitation and what will
>   be the recitation? Who, O great lord, would be meditated on,
>   who would be worshipped, who is to be gratified ? V.Bhai-143 
>
>   To whom is oblation to be offered? For whom is sacrifice
>   to be performed ?' And how is it to be accomplished? V.Bhai- 144**

Actually, Lord Shiva told Devi, everyone is Shiva alone, so Devi is asking then whome to worship, whom to offer etc (above questions). Which Lord Shiva answers in next verses.

> That **creative contemplation** which is practised on the highest
>   Reality over and over again is in this scripture japa (recitation
>   in reality). That which goes on sounding spontaneously (inside)
>   in the form of a mantra  (mystic formula- "**I ParAvAk**" ) is what the japa is
>   about. V.Bhai-145  
>   Worship does not mean offering of flowers, etc. It rather
>   consists in setting one's heart on that highest ether of consciousness
>   which is above all thought-constructs! It really means
>   dissolution of self with perfect ardour (in the Supreme Consciousness
>   known as Bhairava). V.Bhai- 147

---

From Anuttarashtika by AcharArya Abhinavgupta:

> In the oneness of that supreme state of anuttara what talk can there be, and **what differentiated path of adorer, adored and adoration?** To whom and by what means could a progression function; or what could constitute the succession of penetrating into the Self? Wonder of wonders! Though it appears differentiated this illusion is no other than consciousness–one without a second. Everything is nothing but the pure essence of your own Self-experience, so why worry in vain!

From Shiv Stotravalli of AchArya UtpAldeva :
[image]

Comment: This website [translates](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/24) differently. Quote- "A person who is fully absorbed in Kṛṣṇa consciousness is sure to attain the spiritual kingdom because of his full contribution to spiritual activities, in which the consummation is absolute and that which is offered is of the same spiritual nature."

Comment: @DheerajVerma ignore them. It's not accurate.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Although you didn't ask Lord Shiva's reply, I myself added it. I don't think anything left now. You have your answer now.

Answer (score 5):

I can give you the answer according to the dualistic systems of Vedanta. Those are all the Vaishnava systems of Vedanta such as Dvaita, Vishishtadvaita, Acintya bheda abheda (Gaudiya Vaishnava), etc, because they teach the difference between jiva soul (jivatma) and paramatma.

If you pray to the paramatma within yourself that doesn't mean that you are praying to yourself! You are not the paramatma because you are the jivatma, so when you are praying to the paramatma which is within you that doesn't mean that you are praying to yourself! That means that you are praying to him, paramatma, and not to yourself (jivatma).

I explained earlier in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21057/2790) why is there the difference between the two, jivatma and paramatma, and why we shouldn't mistake them as just one soul.
This difference is seen in the verses such as the Mundaka Upanishad 3.1.1:

> **Two birds**, inseparable friends, cling to the same tree. **One of them**
>   eats the sweet fruit, **the other** looks on without eating.

So, when you pray to the paramatma within yourself that means that you are praying to him, the other "bird" which is paramatma, and not to yourself (jivatma). Yes, you can do that, but Vaishnavas usually pray to the Lord Vishnu or Krishna who is that paramatma situated within you.

Comment: In Bhagwat Gita , Lord says that if you pray to anyone then that prayer ultimately reaches him. So if I pray to myself then that prayer should also reach to him.

Comment: @DheerajVerma not any one, any deity.

Comment: @Pandya If the prayers can reach through ghosts and ghouls then why shouldn't through me? One can not put one rule for one being and another rule for another being. I think it is fairly obvious that one can pray to himself or herself and the prayers will reach to the parmatma...

Comment: @DheerajVerma So, what you are saying, then? You think that it's a good idea to pray to yourself (jivatma) and not to the paramatma, and even if you pray to yourself (jivatma) the prayer will ultimately reach Him, the Lord, paramatma?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Yes. This conclusion comes directly from the God's word. I pray to the Parmatma or Jivatma or whatever sacred is inside me. I pray to myself.

Comment: @DheerajVerma The Lord says that those who worship in such a way, their worship is wrong. See the Gita 9.23 https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/23 "they do so in **a wrong way**".

Comment: @brahmajijnasa ok. That means prayers to Jesus , Allah , Guru Sahib, Shiva , Brahma , Ghosts , Ghouls , Indra , Fire,Buddha etc are all done in the wrong way? Only prayers to Krishna are rightful ?

Comment: @DheerajVerma I do not want to comment about other religions and their beliefs, but if we just talk about Hindu beliefs then I would say that, yes, it would be wrong per the teachings of the Gita to pray to other gods such as Shiva, Brahma, Ghosts, Indra, etc, and to neglect Lord Krishna who is the paramatma. I also explained in the answer to your question at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21092/2790 in verse 7.23 the Lord says that less intelligent people think that they should worship gods in heaven and not paramatma, Lord Krishna, instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**.
The lord resides in everyone's hearts, as *Atma*(आत्म) and hence can be prayed upon. If you pray to anyone (beings, ancestors, demons, deva-s), all worshipping reaches to the supreme one.

> BG 10.17 - [Arjuna asked] -- O Yogi, how shall I think of You by remaining ever-engaged in meditation? And through what objects, O Lord, are You to be meditated on by me?
>
> BG 10.20 - O Gudakesa, **I am the Self(*Atma*) residing in the hearts of all beings**, and I am the beginning and the middle as also the end of (all) beings.

---

Depending on what part of the self is prayed upon, one achieves it results.

- If I identify the "self" as my physical body, then I am worshipping a being (*bhuta*); It happens under the influence of *tamas* (ignorance)
- If I identify the "self" as my mind & senses, then I am worshipping my desires; It happens under the influence of *rajas* (passion)
- If I identify the "self" as my intellect or my soul (*Purusha*), then I am worshipping the divinity inside me; It happens under the influence of *sattva*
- If I identify the "self" as none of the above (kind of complete void), then I am worshipping the truest form of the *Atma*

[[source: BG 9.25, 17.4]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20378/1049)